# Can't pass useRef to any elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why doesn't this compile?

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

export function Test() {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>()
  return <div ref={ref} />
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'HTMLDivElement | undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.ts(2322)
```

It seems that `useRef` is defined as

```
function useRef<T = undefined>(): MutableRefObject<T | undefined>
```

While ref attribute type is defined as

```
interface RefObject<T> {
    readonly current: T | null;
}
```

How is it ever supposed to work, if undefined and null are different types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
```

Comment: That worked, seems there's another overload for useRef that uses null instead of undefined. Weird!